# Data from GET request doesn't exist when used in another class in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function for making GET request like this.

```
export class OneClass {
  constructor() {
    this.data = [];

    getData() {
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', '/data.json', true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        * push response to this.data *
      };
      xhr.send();
    }
  }
```

After that I want to use `this.data` in another class, `AnotherClass` is created on `DOMContentLoad`

```
var oneClass = new OneClass();

class AnotherClass {
  constructor() {
    oneClass.getData();
    this.anotherClassMethod()
  }
  anotherClassMethod() {
    * use oneClass.data *
  }
}
```

The idea is that `anotherClassMethod()` should output `oneClass.data` as soon as page is loaded but now when it is called array is still empty.

I understand that my method runs sooner than data is created and that is the reason for it but I'm not sure what to change to make this code work.

Comment: `OneClass` not `oneClass`.

Comment: Pass a callback to `getData` and pass the data to the callback inside `xhr.onreadystatechange`.

Comment: Why would one class directly need data from another? This causes unnecessary coupling. I would consider looking at your approach to how you created the problem instead of the problem itself. Maybe create a service that can meet both needs of the classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you checking the response being valid? If so, why not using the standard way of callback? I've didn't see you implementing it:

```
export class OneClass{
  constructor() {
    this.data = [];

     getData(callback) {
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', '/data.json', true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = (response) => {
        callback(response);
    };
    xhr.send();
  }
}
```

The previous one creates your class with a paremeter for returning to his call stack after finished.
Then, lets wait for the response and manipulate the data:

```
var oneClass= new OneClass();

class AnotherClass{
  constructor() {
    oneClass.getData(this.anotherClassMethod);

  }
 anotherClassMethod(data){
    *use oneClass.data*
 }
}
```

More info on [Callbacks](https://objectreferncehell.wordpress.com/2015/08/20/callbacks-versus-closures-in-javascript/)